# Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "student_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.2

I am developing Spring Data JPA Postgres example. In this example I make the relationship between Student and StudentMember.

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:782) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:763) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.MyProgramApplication.main(MyProgramApplication.java:24) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [student_id]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:296) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.MyProgramApplication.run(MyProgramApplication.java:43) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:779) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3077) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3667) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:800) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:785) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:507) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "student_id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (1, null).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:120) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

**Student.java**

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(name="student_name_key",columnNames = {"studentName"})
})
public class Student{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "studentId")
    private Long studentId;

    @Column(name = "studentName", nullable = false)
    private String studentName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<StudentMember> studentMembers;
}
```

**StudentMember.java**

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class StudentMember {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long studentMemberId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="studentId", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable = false,foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name = "fk_student_id"))
    private Student student;
}
```

MainApp.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyProgramApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    ProgramMemberRepository memberRepository;
    @Autowired
    ProgramRepository programRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyProgramApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Student student = Student.builder().studentName("John Doe").build();
        programRepository.save(student);

        StudentMember programMember = StudentMember.builder()
                .student(student)
                .build();
        if(Objects.nonNull(student.getStudentMembers())){
            student.getStudentMembers().add(programMember);
        } else {
            List<StudentMember> programMembers = new ArrayList<>();
            programMembers.add(programMember);
            student.setStudentMembers(programMembers);
        }

        memberRepository.save(programMember);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Student` relationship in the entity `StudentMember` is read only.

Remove `insertable=false, updatable=false`

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="studentId", nullable = false,foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name = "fk_student_id"))
private Student student;
```

Otherwise Hibernate does not write the foreign key.

Plus I'm not sure if your mapping is correct. PostgreSQL is complaining about a column that is called `student_id` but the name in `@JoinColum` is `studentId`

Check this first.